# Weld archetype vs Seam Forge

Tags: seam, jboss-weld, archetypes, seam3, jboss-forge

I'm building a new project using Seam 3. I don't understand what the difference is between Weld archetype and Seam Forge. Both of them help us to build a simple project template to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seam Forge is a tool similar to seam-gen from Seam 2.
Seam Forge is a console where you can setup and generate your project, you can choose a version of libraries, JPA implementation etc 
you can create classes, add fields to them, create CRUD and many more

weld archetype is a 'simple application' (configuration)  with pom, configuration files and example classes ready to develop your application

I think Seam Forge is stronger tool and have many features helping rapidly develop your application.

Answer (score 3):

In the long run, Forge will be useful for incremental enhancement of your project using extra plugins, like so: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/FORGE/Installing+new+Plugins

This basically lets you extend your project with anything that can be imagined!